# Ionic 3: can't update ion-input's type until I blur/focus back

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this code, so when you click the button with the ion-icon, the password toggles. For that sake I need to change the type of the ion-input, but it only changes after I have blurred or focused the cursor back.

```
<button (click)="input.type = input.type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';"
style="background: white !important;" item-right icon-only>
                            
<ion-icon *ngIf="input.type === 'password'" item-right name="eye">
</ion-icon>
                            
<ion-icon *ngIf="input.type === 'text'" item-right name="eye-off">
</ion-icon>

</button>
```

This problem does not exist when using common HTML input elements, but if I switch to those, I'd lose all styles and functionalities ionic components provide.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to address the input child element beneath the ion-input, using a simple method:

```
callInputChild(){
        this.inputType = this.inputType === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
        document.querySelector("#killswitch > input").setAttribute('type', this.inputType)
        console.log(this.inputType)
    }
```

then in the HTML:

```
<ion-input id="killswitch"></ion-input>
<button (click)="callInputChild()" style="background: white !important;" item-right icon-only>
<ion-icon *ngIf="inputType === 'password'" item-right name="eye"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon *ngIf="inputType === 'text'" item-right  name="eye-off"></ion-icon>
</button>
```